# Customise json output, returning first item from list on Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an API that returns the following json:

```
        {
            "id": 6,
            "lot_no": "787878",
            "product_id": "116110",
            "assay_type": "reascan_crp",
            "valid_from": "2022-11-21",
            "expiry_date": "2022-11-27",
            "is_active": true,
            "last_modified": "2022-11-21T14:29:32.435307Z",
            "teststrips": [
                {
                    "number": 1,
                    "name": "",
                    "control_line_threshold": 1.0,
                    "testlines": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "a": -3.0,
                    "b": -4.0,
                    "c": -6.0,
                    "d": -9.0
                }
            ]
        },
```

however I want the following output without the list on parameters:

```
        {
            "id": 6,
            "lot_no": "787878",
            "product_id": "116110",
            "assay_type": "reascan_crp",
            "valid_from": "2022-11-21",
            "expiry_date": "2022-11-27",
            "is_active": true,
            "last_modified": "2022-11-21T14:29:32.435307Z",
            "teststrips": [
                {
                    "number": 1,
                    "name": "",
                    "control_line_threshold": 1.0,
                    "testlines": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "parameters":
                {
                    "a": -3.0,
                    "b": -4.0,
                    "c": -6.0,
                    "d": -9.0
                }
        },
```

serializers.py :

```
class ParametersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TeststripConfiguration
        fields = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')


class TeststripSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    testlines = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta():
        model = TeststripConfiguration
        fields = ('number', 'name', 'control_line_threshold', 'testlines')

    def get_testlines(self, teststrip):
        upper_negative_testline = None
        lower_positive_testline = None
        if str(teststrip.batch.assay_type) != "reascan_crp":
            upper_negative_testline = teststrip.testlines.values('upper_negative_threshold')[0]['upper_negative_threshold']
            lower_positive_testline = teststrip.testlines.values('lower_positive_threshold')[0]['lower_positive_threshold']
        
        return upper_negative_testline, lower_positive_testline


class BatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parameters = ParametersSerializer(source='teststrips', many=True, read_only=True)
    teststrips = TeststripSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    assay_type = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='name'
    )

    product_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta():
        model = Batch
        fields = ('id', 'lot_no', 'product_id', 'assay_type', 'valid_from', 'expiry_date',
                  'is_active', 'last_modified', 'teststrips', 'parameters')
```

views.py:

```
class CustomPaginator(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 25


class BatchesUpdatedView(ListAPIView, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    """API view to return all batches, their related teststrips and testlines"""
    serializer_class = BatchSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPaginator

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Batch.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        api_latest_update = self.request.query_params.get('latest_update', None)
        if api_latest_update is not None:
            try:
                latest_update = parse_datetime(api_latest_update)
                if latest_update is None:
                    raise TypeError
            except TypeError:
                return Response(
                    {'Error': "Invalid datetime, please make sure it is URL encoded"},
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            if not self.has_batches_been_updated(latest_update):
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
        response = self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        latest_update = Batch.objects.latest_modified_date()
        if latest_update is None:
            response['X-LATEST-UPDATE'] = None
        else:
            response['X-LATEST-UPDATE'] = Batch.objects.latest_modified_date().isoformat()
        return response

    def has_batches_been_updated(self, latest_update) -> bool:
        return True if latest_update < Batch.objects.latest_modified_date() else False
```

I've tried to change parameters = ParametersSerializer(source='teststrips', many=True, read_only=True) to parameters = ParametersSerializer(source='teststrips', many=False, read_only=True) but it returns null as the a,b,c,d values.

**edit**

teststrips model.py:

```
class TeststripConfiguration(models.Model):
    """The Teststrip Configuration for applying thresholds on batches."""
    batch = models.ForeignKey('ndx_batch.Batch', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teststrips')
    number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), blank=True, null=False, max_length=120)
    control_line_threshold = models.FloatField(_("control line threshold"), null=True)
    a = models.FloatField(_("A"), blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    b = models.FloatField(_("B"), blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    c = models.FloatField(_("C"), blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    d = models.FloatField(_("D"), blank=True, null=True, default=0)


    class Meta:  # noqa
        ordering = ('batch',)
        verbose_name = _('teststrip configuration')
        verbose_name_plural = _('teststrip configurations')

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return 'TeststripConfiguration(pk={!r})'.format(self.pk)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Is teststrips a OneToOne Field on the Batch model?

Comment: no it is a foreign key one, I've added the model to the question

Comment: What if you leave off ‘many’ alltogether? Like ParameterSerializer(read_only=True) ?

Comment: it returns null, like many=False

Comment: It makes sense that it will return an array as one Batch could be associated with many teststrips. If it can be only one, you should change the field on the model to a OneToOne Field. Otherwise a hacky way to get what you want is send the single teststrip dict to the serializer and use a DictField. Or you could do that through a SerializerMethodField, but without changing the field on the model, a nested serializer will not get you what you want.